# appropriate phrase for expressing close distances toward a person

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms, vocabulary

Imagine this scenario: You are having a conversation with someone about a tropical fruit which you have seen the picture of (on the internet or something) and do know the name of; but you have **never** seen or touched it in your hand or in a fruit market.

*He*: "What do you think of the papaya?"

*You* : "Oh... ?".

- **oh, I've never seen it before**
- **oh, I've never seen it closely**
- **oh, I've never had it before**

Which clearest answer emphasizing on just you have never seen in front of you(or touched) would be okay in this situation?

Comment: Oh, I  didn't actually see one.

Comment: Does it inform that you also are **familiar** with that, indeed?

Comment: Saying that implies that you know about it.

Comment: I would say *I've only ever seen a picture of one, so I don't know much about them*.

Comment: "I've never seen one in person" (I know this is idiomatic but in the US, that is a common way to convey that you haven't seen something close-up)

Answer (score 2):

I'd say: "I've never seen one [up-close](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/up-close)."

> [ADVERB] At very close range.
>
> *‘he was able to experience glaciers calving up-close’*

(Oxford)

It's worth noting that the ODO entry doesn't list any synonyms.